# ignore -webkit-box-shadow and -moz-box-shadow while using stylelint in angular

Tags: css, angular, stylelint

How can I remove stylelint rule for CSS properties like `-webkit-box-shadow` and `-moz-box-shadow`? Because it is overwriting to `box-shadow` when I run `--fix` command.

Below is my `.stylelintrc.json` file rule list:

```
{
  "extends": "stylelint-config-recommended-scss",
  "plugins": ["stylelint-order"],
  "rules": {
    "order/properties-alphabetical-order": true,
    "at-rule-no-unknown": null,
    "no-eol-whitespace": null,
    "indentation": 2,
    "number-leading-zero": null,
    "at-rule-no-vendor-prefix": true,
    "media-feature-name-no-vendor-prefix": true,
    "property-no-vendor-prefix": true,
    "selector-no-vendor-prefix": true,
    "value-no-vendor-prefix": true,
    "string-quotes": "single",
    "at-rule-name-case": null,
    "no-invalid-position-at-import-rule": null,
    "scss/at-import-partial-extension": null,
    "no-empty-source": null,
    "no-descending-specificity": null,
    "selector-pseudo-element-no-unknown": [
      true,
      {
        "ignorePseudoElements": ["ng-deep", "input-placeholder"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any option to add a rule for particular `CSS property`? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`ignoreProperties` secondary option](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/list/property-no-vendor-prefix/#ignoreproperties-regex-regex-string) of the [`property-no-vendor-prefix` rule](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/list/property-no-vendor-prefix) to specify which properties you don't want to unprefix.

For example, to ignore `box-shadow`:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "property-no-vendor-prefix": [true, { "ignoreProperties": ["box-shadow"] }]
  }
}
```